# run cordova app without local server

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, json, cordova

I'm trying to run cordova app using this html page the page works well on the local server but does not run in the app. Page fetches data from json file. Json file contains longitude and latitude which are used for locating marker on the map.

```
<html>
<head>
<style type="text/css">
body { height: 100%; margin: 0; padding: 0 }
#map_canvas { height: 100% }
</style>
<script type="text/javascript" src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-latest.min.js"></script> 

    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1, maximum-scale=1.0, user-scalable=no">
    <script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.9.1.min.js"></script>
    <script src="http://code.jquery.com/mobile/1.3.1/jquery.mobile-1.3.1.min.js"></script>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="http://code.jquery.com/mobile/1.3.1/jquery.mobile-1.3.1.min.css" />
    <meta http-equiv="Content-Security-Policy" content="default-src 'self' data: gap: https://ssl.gstatic.com 'unsafe-eval'; style-src 'self' 'unsafe-inline'; media-src *">
    <meta name="format-detection" content="telephone=no">
    <meta name="msapplication-tap-highlight" content="no">
    <meta name="viewport" content="user-scalable=no, initial-scale=1, maximum-scale=1, minimum-scale=1, width=device-width">
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="css/index.css">
    <title>Hello World</title>

    <script type="text/javascript" src="cordova.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="js/index.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" src = "http://maps.google.com/maps/api/js?key=AIzaSyBOliLL5Jrj-MH1-H-MspEVqJZn61uJP_0&sensor=false">
    </script>
    <script type="text/javascript">

    var Latit;
    var Longi;
    var i;
    $(function(){
            if (navigator.userAgent.match(/(iPhone|iPod|iPad|Android|BlackBerry)/)) {

                document.addEventListener("deviceready", getPosition, false);
            } else {
                getPosition(); //this is the browser
            }
        })

       function getPosition() {

       var options = {
       enableHighAccuracy: true,
       maximumAge: 3600000
       }

       var watchID = navigator.geolocation.getCurrentPosition(onSuccess, onError, options);

       function onSuccess(position) {


 Latit = position.coords.latitude;
 Longi = position.coords.longitude;        
 };

  function onError(error) {
  alert('code: '    + error.code    + '\n' + 'message: ' + error.message + '\n');
  }
    }

   function initialize() {

    var point = new google.maps.LatLng(Latit,Longi);

     var map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById('map_canvas'), {
   zoom: 15,
  center: point,
  mapTypeId: google.maps.MapTypeId.ROADMAP
});

  // Place a marker
  new google.maps.Marker({
  position: point,
  animation:google.maps.Animation.BOUNCE,
  map: map
  });



     $.getJSON('map_points.json', function(data) { //function requires local server
        $.each( data.points, function(i, value) {



            var myLatlng = new google.maps.LatLng(value.lat,value.lon);
            var marker = new google.maps.Marker({
            position: myLatlng,
            map: map,
            title: "position:"+value.lat+" , "+value.lon
            });

        google.maps.event.addListener(marker,'click',function() {
            var infoWindow = new google.maps.InfoWindow({
               content:'Address: '+value.Address
              });
         infoWindow.open(map,marker);
        });

        });
     });
    }

   </script>
  </head>
  <body onload="initialize()">
  <form id="form1" runat="server">
  <div id="map_canvas" style="width: 500px; height: 400px"></div>
  </form>
  <div> 
  </div>
    </body>
    </html>
```

Json code attached with it is:

```
  {

  "points":[
 {"id":1,"lat":19.031166126834226,"lon":72.88102626800537,"Address":"imax"},{"id":2,"lat":19.073332920257027,"lon":72.89924383163452,"Address":"somaiya"},
 {"id":3,"lat":19.13302550300137,"lon": 72.91306257247925,"Address":"IIT Bombay"},
  {"id":4,"lat":19.123000520026086,"lon":72.9127112030983, "Address":"Gateway Plaza"}
   ]


  }
```

Comment: What do you mean by local server?

Comment: localhost using apache server.

Comment: OK, and how does it not run in Cordova? You need to provide more details on your problem.

Comment: It displays nothing in the app when compiled and build using cordova.